# Convert double to Animation<double> in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter

I want to pass a fixed value to a `Transition` sometimes, something like:

```
return FadeTransition(
  opacity: widget.hasOpacity ? animation : 1.0,
...
```

But of course this doesn't work, as `opacity` doesn't accept a `double`, just an `Animation<double`.

Are there any easy ways to convert a `double` into an `Animation<double>`?

Currently I am creating a dummy `Animation<double>` just for this, as:

```
opaqueAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 1.0).animate(curve);
```

and then using it as:

```
return FadeTransition(
  opacity: widget.hasOpacity ? animation : opaqueAnimation,
...
```

Answer (score 9):

`AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(1)` is meant for this, so the code becomes:

```
return FadeTransition(
  opacity: widget.hasOpacity ? animation : AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(1),
...
```

Comment: I did something like this `AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(_animationController.value);`  but it didn't work :(

Comment: The crazy thing is that it does work with the `TweenAnimationBuilder` XD